# How to add Docker option to run from VS2022 for .NET Core project

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio, .net-core

How to add Docker option for build program in Visual Studio 2022?

For example, when I create a new solution and check Docker, then I have the option:

[image]

But in the solution that I didn't use Docker before, and created some `dockerfile`, I don't have option Docker for my solution?

Should I add something in `.csproj` file?

Also I was looking at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/overview?view=vs-2022) but I can't find Docker support in the project tab in VS 2022

Comment: Check if this helps: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-docker-support-option-missing/418220

Comment: Hello, are you sure your project is a .net core project? If you are sure then which version of the .net framework is your project using? I'm using .net 6.0 and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In VS2022, right click the project you want to add Docker to and choose "Add" and then choose "Docker Support". You will be prompted if you want to run the project in a linux or windows container.

A default Docker file will be added to your project and the projects launchSettings.json updated with a Docker alternative.

```
{
 "profiles": {
   "ConnectEF": {
     "commandName": "Project"
   },
   "Docker": {
     "commandName": "Docker"
    }
  }
}
```

You can then run the project with Docker as usual.

[image: Docker Image]

Comment: This menu is not showing for me, with VS 2022 and .NET Core 8.0 :(

Comment: @TBG check your VS installation - if the "container development tool" is on.

Comment: @SerG Yeah I had to go back to the installer and tick that, thanks ! However for WebAssembly projects, you still need to do it yourself, no Docker Support menu